# Running Observables in a Service

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-android, rxandroidble

I have set up an `RxAndroidBle Observable/Subscriber` to receive and log data from several Bluetooth LE peripherals. It is inside an Android `Service`, which currently is of the Bound variety (to 2 different Activities).

I was planning to add the "Started Service" features to this `Service` so it could continue to run when the Activities are suspended, but in early tests it looks like this isn't necessary: it seems to continue running when the App is in the background. I don't understand why this works, because the Android docs say that when all Activities unbind from a `Bound Service`, it will be destroyed (both of my Activities call `unbind()` in their `onStop()` methods).

What's going on here? Is the existence of an active `Observable` somehow keeping the `Service` alive? What, if anything, should I do to manage this?

Comment: Did you check if onDestroy() of the Service is called when you unbind?

Comment: It appears that `onDestroy()` of the `Service` is not being called.

Comment: Wondering if `onDestroy()` isn't being called simply because Android hasn't gotten around to it yet. Can it come along at any moment and tank my Service?

Comment: Dariusz Seweryn: Would really like to get a response from Polidea on this

Comment: No onDestroy is called at a determinate time. Might be garbage collected later though if possible. Are you sure service is not started some other way.

Comment: The app has 2 activities. They both bind to the service in the typical way, and unbind in either `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`. No command (that I can find) is ever called to start the service. Yet the Observables keep running merrily along when the app is backgrounded. I'm not complaining: this is the desired behavior. I'd just like to understand why it works without the service ever being formally started.

Comment: Try it without observables and see if onDestroy is called. Post minimum test case on github if possible.